# I'm passing the correct java.io.File parameter to transferTo, but it's not being accepted

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I've been trying to save an uploaded file to my local drive.
This is my current code for saving the file:

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
def f = request.getFile('file')

    if(f.empty)
    {
        render "Please go back and select a file."
    }
    else
    {
        CommonsMultipartFile cmfile = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("file");
        def filename = cmfile.originalFilename
        def filepath = new File("C:/Monthly_Stat/RNC/"+filename)
        f.transferTo(filepath)
    }
```

There are no problems when uploading and reading the file.
But when I try to save it on my local drive, this is error code that is returned to me:

> No signature of method: `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transerTo()` is applicable for argument types: (`java.io.File`) values: `[C:\Monthly_Stat\RNC\sample_import.xls`] Possible solutions: `transferTo(java.io.File)`

The confusing thing is, I am passing a `java.io.File` parameter but it is saying as if it is not a `java.io.File`

What could be the problem with this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that is not the actual code you are using, as I cannot see where you get `mpr` from when you call `(CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("file");`.  Can you post the real code that is failing, and not an invalid approximation of it?

Comment: Yah, sorry. I pasted the code missing 1 line. *edited.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the files? http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0064.html suggests that there are limitations on how big files can be copied.

I have had problems with the transferTo method, it didn't work copying between different disks, just on the same disk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The file I'm uploading is just a sample file. Just to try if I can save the uploaded file to my local drive. I'm not copying an existing file from one drive to another. I'm saving an uploaded file which is not yet existing in the local drive.